# Laravel - Routes GET|HEAD

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

When I do `php artisan routes`, the `GET` request of my app has a `|HEAD`. What is the purpose of having `|HEAD`?

**Routes.php**

```
+--------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                              | Name                         | Action                               | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD /                       | home                         | HomeController@home                  |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD user/{username}         | profile-user                 | ProfileController@user               |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD account/change-password | account-change-password      | AccountController@getChangePassword  | auth           |               |
|        | GET|HEAD asset/encode-file/{id}  | encode-file                  | EncodeController@getEncode           | auth           |               |
|        | GET|HEAD asset/edit-file/{id}    | edit-file                    | AssetController@getEdit              | auth           |               |
|        | GET|HEAD asset/delete-file/{id}  | delete-file                  | AssetController@deleteDestroy        | auth           |               |
|        | GET|HEAD asset/upload-file-form  | upload-file-form             | AssetController@getUploadCreate      | auth           |               |
|        | GET|HEAD asset/library           | asset-library                | AssetController@getAssetLib          | auth           |               |
|        | GET|HEAD account/sign-out        | account-sign-out             | AccountController@getSignOut         | auth           |               |
|        | GET|HEAD account/activate/{code} | account-activate             | AccountController@getActivate        | guest          |               |
|        | GET|HEAD account/forgot-password | account-forgot-password      | AccountController@getForgotPassword  | guest          |               |
|        | GET|HEAD account/recover/{code}  | account-recover              | AccountController@getRecover         | guest          |               |
|        | GET|HEAD account/sign-in         | account-sign-in              | AccountController@getSignIn          | guest          |               |
|        | GET|HEAD account/create          | account-create               | AccountController@getCreate          | guest          |               |
+--------+----------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Could you, please, show your routes.php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following function is taken from the `Laravel'`s `Illuminate\Routing\Router.php`  class, when you use `Route::get()` method to add a route for your site/application, `Laravel` adds both methods for the `url`, it means that, these `url`s registered using `get`method could be accessed using both `GET` and `HEAD` `HTTP` method, and [HEAD](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) is just another `HTTP` verb/method, used for making a `HEAD` request.

```
/**
 * Register a new GET route with the router.
 *
 * @param  string  $uri
 * @param  \Closure|array|string  $action
 * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route
 */
public function get($uri, $action)
{
    return $this->addRoute(array('GET', 'HEAD'), $uri, $action);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The `HEAD` request is almost identical to a `GET` request, they only differ by a single fundamental aspect: **the `HEAD` response should not include a payload (the actual data).**

This makes the **HEAD HTTP verb** fundamental for managing the validity of your current cached data.

The value for a header field in the response of your `HEAD` request will warn you if your data is not up-to-date. After that you can make a proper `GET` request retrieving the updated data.

This can be achieved observing the `Content-Length` field or the `Last-Modified` field for example.

When working with large payloads, caching your data and making `HEAD` requests before the actual `GET` to check the validity of you current data can save you big money on data consumption.

You will know precisely when to retrieve the full payload.

The big question is: **why is Laravel combining `HEAD` and `GET` HTTP verbs when you use `Route::get()`?**

You can use `Route::match('HEAD')` to register your HEAD request, but I find it weird that we don't have `Route::head()`.

From the HTTP RFC:

> The HEAD method is identical to GET except that the server MUST NOT return a message-body in the response. The metainformation contained in the HTTP headers in response to a HEAD request SHOULD be identical to the information sent in response to a GET request. This method can be used for obtaining metainformation about the entity implied by the request without transferring the entity-body itself. This method is often used for testing hypertext links for validity, accessibility, and recent modification.
>
> The response to a HEAD request MAY be cacheable in the sense that the information contained in the response MAY be used to update a previously cached entity from that resource. If the new field values indicate that the cached entity differs from the current entity (as would be indicated by a change in Content-Length, Content-MD5, ETag or Last-Modified), then the cache MUST treat the cache entry as stale.

Comment: On the "big question": I would guess that since a `HEAD` request should result in the same internal actions (only the body is not sent), Laravel considers it good to always offer a `HEAD` route alongside any `GET` route. In the very rare and special cases where a separate `HEAD` should exist, the developer can use `Route::match`. IMHO not worth the extra helper function `Route::head()`.