# Why laravel landing page route return MethodNotAllowedHttpException?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I'm using laravel 7.x.
since `function(){return view(welcome);}` will produce an error when I run `php artisan route:cache`, so I write this code below to replace `function()`:

```php
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index')->name('welcome');
```

It run well on `php artisan serve` command.
But when i run directly from `public` folder, it produce exception `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. I couldn't find why it happened, could you help me why it happened?

exception message:

```php
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: HEAD.
https://localhost/laravel-tester/public/
```

WelcomeController Method

```php
public function index(){
   return view('welcome');
}
```

Comment: run `php artisan route:clear` and try again.

Comment: thank you, I started to understand how it return error. Your solution is working, but it's still give error when route is cached. I'll try to look at route.php again to figure out why it give error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Routes GET|HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118598/laravel-routes-gethead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

::get registers the route for methods GET and HEAD by default. You are trying to access it with a GET request (as you should) but it does not return it. Possibly there is something wrong with your Router class, so please check your Routing\Router.php class against the method in the comment below.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22119028/10187949